# Incremental Summation for the Same Quarter in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

How to get the output as above scene.

Comment: how could we have a cumulative sum if we don't know which row of goes first in for the same quarter?. Does the order matter there?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: order does not matter, just need to sum of each row with the same Quarter and if it belong to same year.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Queries with sample data.

Now since you don't have any field which could be used for ordering inside a quarter, I used row_number to generate row number and then used that in order by clause of outer window function.

```
create table #Customers(Year int, Quarter varchar(10), amount int)

insert into #customers values(2020,'Q1',100)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q1',150)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q1',150)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q1',300)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q2',400)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q2',400)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q2',400)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q2',500)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q3',-200)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q3',-200)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q3',300)
insert into #customers values(2020,'Q3',-500)

select
Year,Quarter, Amount,
sum(amount) over(partition by Year,Quarter order by rnum) as cummulative_amount
from 
(
select *,
row_number() over(order by Year, quarter,amount) rnum
from
#Customers
) a
```